# How to point go module to a local module which is not yet pushed to Git

Tags: go-modules

**What do I have**:

1. private repository
2. sub-module in the repository

```
submodule/
 submodule.go
 go.mod
 go.sum
main.go
go.mod
go.sum
```

`go.mod` contains

```
module github.com/username/privaterepo

go 1.16

require github.com/username/privaterepo/submodule latest

replace (
    github.com/username/privaterepo/submodule latest => target ./submodule
)
```

`submodule/go.mod` contains

```
module github.com/username/privaterepo/submodule

go 1.16
```

I didn't push anything to the repository yet. I'm trying to `go mod tidy` in the root of my app:

```
$ env GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 go mod tidy
Username for 'https://github.com': username
Password for 'https://username@github.com': 
go: errors parsing go.mod:
<...>/go.mod:5: no matching versions for query "latest"
<...>/go.mod:8:2: no matching versions for query "latest"
```

Which version should I use for my local submodule which is not pushed to the repository yet? Is it even possible to use such local submodule when it's not pushed to the repository (I thought that `go mod` wouldn't even go to remote source when it sees `replace`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed `go.mod` with

```
module github.com/username/privaterepo

go 1.16

require github.com/username/privaterepo/submodule v0.0.0 //version changed to v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000 after go mod tidy

replace github.com/username/privaterepo/submodule => ./submodule
```